# WHERE clause over row_to_json Node postgres

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm using the following query to retrieve some data from my postgres db:

```
pool.query(`
  SELECT a.*, row_to_json(u.*) as users 
  FROM artworks a INNER JOIN users u USING(address) 
  WHERE (a.flag != ($1) OR a.flag IS NULL) 
  ORDER BY a.date DESC LIMIT 1000`, 
["ILLEGAL"]).then(users => {
  if (users) {
    res.json(users.rows);
  } 
  }).catch(err => {
    next(err);
  })
```

I now also want add a condition for users in the WHERE clause so i added the following:

**AND u.status == ($2)**

```
pool.query(`
  SELECT a.*, row_to_json(u.*) as users 
  FROM artworks a INNER JOIN users u USING(address) 
  WHERE (a.flag != ($1) OR a.flag IS NULL) 
  AND u.status == ($2) 
  ORDER BY a.date DESC LIMIT 1000`, 
["ILLEGAL", "VERIFIED"]).then(users => {
  if (users) {
    res.json(users.rows);
  } 
  }).catch(err => {
    next(err);
  })
```

But i'm getting the following error:

***operator does not exist: character varying == unknown***

Any idea what i'm doing wrong please?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was very simple..., in SQL "equal" is = not ==

Sorry about that, im new to it :)